# Does Fortran 2003 implementation of deferred bound procedure requires same argument?

Tags: function, oop, fortran, deferred, abstract-data-type

I tried to create inside a module an abstract type

```
type, abstract :: AbsType
    contains
     procedure (Compute_AbsSize), deferred :: AbsSize
end type AbsType
abstract interface
    function Compute_AbsSize(this)
        import AbsType
        double precision Compute_AbsSize
        class(AbsType)::this
    end function Compute_AbsSize
end interface

type, extends(AbsType) :: ConcrType
     type(Var), dimension(4) :: Nodes ! coming from a module
    contains
     procedure :: AbsSize => ConcrTypeSize
end type ConcrType

contains

function ConcrTypeSize(this)
        double precision ConcrTypeSize
        class (ConcrType):: this        ! 
end function ConcrTypeSize
```

It turns out that if I write

```
function ConcrTypeSize(TheConcrType)
        double precision ConcrTypeSize
        class (ConcrType):: TheConcrType        ! 
end function ConcrTypeSize
```

the compiler (gcc) complains that TheConcrType should have the same name of the variable of the deferred function. I could not find this information, does anybody know why I have to do this, and is this correct?

**Edit**: I moved the last part of the quetion to
[this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391094/is-it-possible-to-implement-an-abstract-variable-inside-a-type-in-fortran-2003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A specific binding in an extension that overrides a specific binding in the parent type must have dummy arguments that match in name and characteristics, bar the type of the passed argument, if any.  This is explained in the F2008 standard in section 4.5.7.3 (similar words in F2003).

The compiler is therefore correct to complain.  Remember that the name of a dummy argument can be used when the procedure is referenced, and may also be used in the PASS attribute for the binding.  A mismatch in argument names doesn't make sense in those contexts.

With respect to you last paragraph it is not clear to me exactly what you want, or how that relates to the previous part of the question.  However, note that components can be allocatable.  Each object of type with an allocatable component could have the component allocated to a different size.  Similarly, while dummy arguments in bound procedures must have matching characteristics, and a characteristic of a dummy argument is its shape, that shape could be assumed shape.

Comment: For the last part maybe it is better to put it in a separate question. Regarding the main question my main point is that as I use the extended type I would like to make it explicit in the dummy argument using a name closer to the actual function (for instance a car type instead of an abstract type). Anyway thank you for the answet and the reference!

Comment: I edited the question and put the last part in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391094/is-it-possible-to-implement-an-abstract-variable-inside-a-type-in-fortran-2003

Comment: The specific procedure that implements the binding (and hence has a requirement for matching dummy argument names) could always forward to another procedure that has a different dummy argument name.