# Fortran 2003, can data be deferred in an abstract type?

Tags: oop, fortran, deferred, abstract-data-type

I know it's possible to defer the definition of procedures from an abstract type to its derived types. Is it possible to include **'deferred' data** in an abstract type, i.e., **data whose type and value is only defined in derived classes**?

The closest question I found on stackoverflow was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391094/is-it-possible-to-implement-an-abstract-variable-inside-a-type-in-fortran-2003). It does not address my needs.

If clarification is needed, please ask. Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is an incorrect use of the [deferred] tag. Not quite sure enough to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to defer the definition of a data component of an (abstract) derived type as there is for procedure components, so no declaration such as

```
type(magic), deferred :: element
```

which can be overridden by a concrete declaration in an extended type.  I think the easy (?) workaround would be to use `class` in the declaration.  For ultimate flexibility you could use an unlimited polymorphic component, *eg*

```
type :: stype
    class(*), allocatable :: element
end type style
```

What you can't then do is specify the type in a concrete extended type with a (re-)declaration something like

```
type, extends(stype) :: mstype
    integer :: element
end type mstype
```

Instead, if you want to define an extended type which has an `integer` element you would create the type and write a constructor for it that ensures its `element` is allocated with type `integer`.

If your requirements are more modest the 2003 feature of *parameterised derived types* might satisfy you, but as far as I know only the Cray and IBM XL compilers implement that yet.

Comment: `class(*)` component has to be allocatable or pointer. And I don't believe such redeclaration is possible in the extended type.

Comment: You're right @VladimirF, about the allocatability of the element, that'll learn me to write code without a compiler !